# Time complexity of Andrew's algorithm (complex hull)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, convex-hull

According to [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain), the Andrew's algorithm runs in linear time if all the points are already sorted. We will take the case of sorted points.

However, in the pseudo code it says:

```
for i = 1, 2, ..., n:
while L contains at least two points and the sequence of last two points
        of L and the point P[i] does not make a counter-clockwise turn:
    remove the last point from L
append P[i] to L
```

Now, here we can see a for loop and a while loop nested inside of the for loop. According to my logic reasoning, if there is a loop inside a loop, it simply can not have in a linear time complexity.

Where am I making the mistake?
Thanks!

EDIT: By analyzing the code, I deduced following.

```
for i loop--------O(n)
    while loop----O(i-2) worst case
        remove----O(1)
    append--------O(1)
```

Now, if the while loop had the time complexity of O(n), the overall complexity would be O(n^2). But because it is smaller, the overall complexity should be O((i-2) * n), which I think is bigger than O(n) because i increments to n...

I am not really sure how to calculate this correctly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you do have linear complexity because:

For (i=1 ... n) grants an n factor to the complexity so until now O(n)

In the nested while loop you have the condition (L size >= 2 && it will also check if you do make a counter-clockwise turn(that should be done in constant time)). So this may apear to scale the complexity to a factor of n as well(that would produce an quadratic complexity O(n*n))

But now the thing is the body of the nested while loop can be executed at most N times because there you are pop-ing elements from L; and you are not pushing elements in L except once for every i. So in the execution of the algorithm the push(append) statement will be executed exactly N times and thus the POP(remove last element) can be executed at most N times regardless the fact it is nested in an enclosing for loop. Thus, the complexity remains O(n) = linear complexity.

Comment: Very nice answer. It works out through the amortized analysis.

Comment: Really elegant explanation! Got it as soon as I read it... Thanks Javatar! :)